# How can I get an "OR" condition within CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a query that matches certain criteria OR matches an exact ID

This is the query I want:

```
SELECT * WHERE (`Listing.Color` = 'red' AND `Listing.Doors` = 2) OR Listing.ID = 75
```

This is the query I get when debuggin:

```
SELECT * WHERE `Listing.Color` = 'red' AND `Listing.Doors` = 2 AND Listing.ID = 75
```

Here is my code:

```
$conditions = array();

$conditions[] = array('Listing.Color' => 'red');
$conditions[] = array('Listing.Doors' => 4);

$conditions[] =  array( 
        "OR" => array(
            array('Listing.ID' => 75)
             ),
         );

return $conditions;

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
);    


$this->set('listings', $this->paginate());
```

I have also tried these combinations (along with a bunch of others)

```
$conditions["OR"][] = array('Listing.ID' => 75);
$conditions[]["OR"] = array('Listing.ID' => 75);
$conditions[]["OR"][] = array('Listing.ID' => 75);
$conditions["OR"][] = array('Listing.ID' => 75);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
         array('Listing.Color' => 'red', 'Listing.Doors' => 4),
         array('Listing.ID' => 75)
     )        
);

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
);
```

Also, why do you have `return $conditions;` just after you create your $conditions array?

Comment: I've updated my desired query so you can get a better idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, see my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the items you're OR'ing in the OR condition.  Also, that inner array around 'Listing.ID' => 75 should only necessary if you're doing on OR on the same field like Listing.ID = 75 OR Listing.ID = 25.  Try the following (haven't tested it, obviously)

```
$conditions[] =  array( 
    "OR" => array(
            'Listing.ID' => 75,
            'Listing.Doors' => 4,
         ),
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conditions["AND"] = array( 'Listing.Color' => 'red',  Listing.Doors' => 2 );
$conditions["OR"] = array( 'Listing.ID' => 75 );
```

Comment: I've updated my desired query so you can get a better idea of what I'm looking for.